# How do I use grep to generate

Tags: grep

How would I generate a list that displays the lowest numbers in a file?

ex.

1. List item 
   2476 Jackie Woodson :manager: :sales: :05/01/59: **110000**
2. List item
   2000 Jack Wilson :director: :accounts: :04/19/55: **80000**
3. List item
   7700  Wilson Ali :executie: :accounts: :08/30/56: **90000**
4. List item 
   3364 Bill Wilcocks :manager: :sales: :12/12/55: **65000**
5. List item
   4290 Neil O'bryan :executive: :accounts: :05/01/59: **100000**
6. List item
   2000  Wilson Albert :Chairman: :productions: :03/12/50: **125000**

I want to list the show the range between 60000 and 9000 and list only those using grep

I've tried

grep "[69]" .....$ filename

Comment: Use http://askubuntu.com/editing-help and post your exact file content and desired output from that.

Comment: perhaps: 90000 ?

Answer (score 2):

`grep` does not do numeric comparisons, and is not the tool to use here. I'd use:

```
sort --field-separator=":" --numeric-sort --reverse --key=7 --ignore-leading-blanks filename | \
    tail --lines=3  | \
    sort --field-separator=":" --numeric-sort --key=7 --ignore-leading-blanks
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is line matching tool, which means it only matches lines which has specific text. What you want is text processing utility, such as `awk` that can do comparisons.

```
$ awk -F ':' '$NF > 60000 && $NF<90000' list.txt                                  
List item 2000 Jack Wilson :director: :accounts: :04/19/55: 80000
List item 3364 Bill Wilcocks :manager: :sales: :12/12/55: 65000
```

The way this works is simple:

- `-F ':'` tells awk to treat each line as set of words separated by colons
- `'$NF > 60000 && $NF<90000'`  will look at the last word `$NF` , and check if it's greater than 60000 AND (the `&&` part) 90000.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -P '\b[6-8]\d{4}\s*$' ex3
```

Comment: -P, --perl-regexp
              Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl  regular  expression  (PCRE, see
              below).  This is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of
              unimplemented features.

Comment: @ElderGeek, in fact this option is present just in some grep implementations such as gnugrep -- the grep available in ubuntu. Although  experimental this option in available for years and is very robust and widely used

Comment: Do you think that information might be suitable to [edit] into your answer? (comments can be deleted for a number of reasons)